# Change position of icon in valueBox

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shinywidgets

Suppose you have a simple `valueBox()` from the `shinydashboard` package:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(width = 12, 
             valueBoxOutput("box")
    )
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$box<-renderValueBox(     

    valueBox(
      value = "ValueBox Title",
      subtitle = tagList("Some information about the box.",
                         p(""),
                         "Some more information about the box.",
                         p(""),
                         "Even more information about the box.",
                         shinyWidgets::progressBar(id = "test", value = 10, total = 10, display_pct = FALSE, striped = FALSE, status = "danger")
      ),
      icon = icon("user-check"),
      color = "green"
    ))

}

app<-shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp(app, host="0.0.0.0",port=5050, launch.browser = TRUE)
```

I have added some extra information into the `valueBox()` like some extra subtitles and a progress bar. You'll notice, however, that the `valueBox` icon is aligned to the *bottom right* of the box, meaning that the progress bar (or other content) can get in the way of the icon. Is there a simple way to align `valueBox` icons to the *top right* of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done through CSS.

Add `tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.small-box .icon-large {top: 5px;}')))` to the body and you should be good to go.

Full code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(

    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.small-box .icon-large {top: 5px;}'))),

    fluidRow(width = 12, 
             valueBoxOutput("box")
    )
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$box<-renderValueBox(     

    valueBox(
      value = "ValueBox Title",
      subtitle = tagList("Some information about the box.",
                         p(""),
                         "Some more information about the box.",
                         p(""),
                         "Even more information about the box.",
                         shinyWidgets::progressBar(id = "test", value = 10, total = 10, display_pct = FALSE, striped = FALSE, status = "danger")
      ),
      icon = icon("user-check"),
      color = "green"
    ))

}

app<-shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
runApp(app, host="0.0.0.0",port=5050, launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Comment: Lovely, thanks very much @Kevin for your answer. Works as expected.

Comment: This solution will change position of the icon for all valueBox right? Isn't it possible to decide the position of the icon within one specific valueBox() instead?